# how to use uddi in .Net

Tags: .net, uddi

I have used web services in .Net before with WCF.Though, I don't really understand the benefits of UDDI. There is a lot of theory but I didn't find anything practical. Do you know any tutorials on using UDDi in .NET?

Comment: really, nobody has a clue what is UDDI good for?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found [an example of UDDI in .Net](http://www.15seconds.com/issue/030326.htm)

Another example about [UDDI based enterprise SOA](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/uddiservicefactory.aspx) from codeproject

MSDN articles [Part 1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms953944.aspx) and [Part 2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms953948.aspx)

Comment: do you know anybody using UDDI?

Answer (score 0):

jUDDI has a .net port for accessing UDDI resources.

http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/juddi/trunk/juddi-client.net/